# Displaying fa icon at the end of text in the given design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a design like I mentioned in below screenshot where I want to display fa icon above end of text. Someone please help me to design like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi, please note that SO isnt a free code writing service. Askers are expected to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us the problems you are facing while attempting this. Goodluck :D

Comment: Is thaat icon to  be clickable? And/or is the accompanying text to be clickable?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `<sup></sup>` in HTML, this is an example replace X with whatever you want.

```html
More information<sup>X</sup>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work , put your icon instead of 22

#### Total Sales <sup>22</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML sup tag on a Fontawesome icon in the same way as you would use it on an 'ordinary' character.

So for example to put the free Fontawesome info icon as a superscript you could do:

```
<div class="info">Total sales<sup><i class="fas fa-info"></i></sup></div>
```

From  your image it looks as though you are using the Pro version of Fontawesome in which case substitute whatever the correct class is for the info icon with a circle round it instead of fa-info.